how to emulate base::plot with ggplot R, with many time series
I am plotting about 50 time series, all of which are, to some extent,  overlapping.
Doing so with base::plot returns a messy plot, but I can at least see that many series are being plotted.
Doing the same thing with ggplot returns a chart in which, essentially, only the first series is visible.
MWE:
library(xts) 

prova <- xts(do.call(cbind,lapply(1:50, \(x)rnorm(1000))), as.yearmon(seq.Date(as.Date("2024-01-01"), length.out = 1000, by = '1 month')))

plot(prova)

ggplot(melt(as.data.table(prova), id.vars = "index", variable.name = "var", value.name = "value"), aes(index, value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = var)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

I don't think the difference lies in the color scheme only, nor in the thickness of the lines. Is there a way to get a result in ggplot that is similar to the base plot?
Any more insight on why the two differ so much?
I attach an example of the two outputs (with different dates from the MWE).



Can you articulate the difference that you're interested in, if it is not the colour or linewidth of the lines?

I think the issue is primarily due to the default ggplot2 color palette working poorly in this application. Try scale_color_manual(values = Polychrome::createPalette(50, c("#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff")) |> rlang::set_names(NULL)) for one option that seems acceptable to me.

@teunbrand I am interested in having the same "distinguishability" of the series in the plot. I do not know if this passes by the lines' thickness/color only, but I though it does not because of trials I did on my own - might be wrong though.

@JonSpring got it.  I will try the Polychrome solution if other solutions do not work well enough, thank you - I prefer not to load additional packages

The code in the question is calling plot.xts which in turn is calling base plot. We will simplify the example by using plot.zoo and autoplot.zoo which ultimately call base plot and ggplot2 respectively.
To ensure consistent colors specify the colors (col below).
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)

# inputs
set.seed(123)
prova <- xts(matrix(rnorm(1000 * 50), 1000), as.yearmon("2024-01") + (0:999)/12)
col <- 1:50

plot.zoo(prova, col = col, screen = 1)

autoplot.zoo(prova, facet = NULL) +   
  scale_color_manual(values = col) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")




ok, so essentially the color code was defined by a integers sequence. got it.

Also colors() and packages: RColorBrewer and colorspace .

Obviously @G. Grothendieck's answer shows how to make exactly the same plot, validating @John Spring's comment.
I am of the opinion that the line width is a legitimate issue in addition to the color, so here is a quick and dirty solution that does both. It looks like ggplot2 is calling rainbow() under the hood (?) to generate those colors, and that purple/pink on top is pretty bad for visualization, which you can ameliorate somewhat by just reversing that palette, again using scale_color_manual().
I'm of the opinion that the ggplot2 figure is now significantly more informative than the base plot (though you can of course do similar stuff with the base plot to make it nicer!):
library(xts)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

prova <- xts(do.call(cbind,lapply(1:50, \(x)rnorm(1000))), as.yearmon(seq.Date(as.Date("2024-01-01"), length.out = 1000, by = '1 month')))

plot(prova)

ggplot(melt(as.data.table(prova), id.vars = "index", variable.name = "variable", value.name = "value"), aes(index, value)) +
     geom_line(aes(color = variable), size=.05) +
     theme(legend.position = "none") + 
     scale_color_manual(values = rev(rainbow(50)))




The comment you refer to tried to create a different color scheme that looks similar but that is not what my answer shows.  It shows how to use exactly the same color scheme in both examples.

@G.Grothendieck: certainly, what I think was validated was that the visualization was in fact negatively impacted by the ggplot2 default palette, contrary to OP's expectation. I do not take any position on the right way to create a palette or what palette should be used. Indeed, (and here I am reading between the lines I do admit) OP does not seem to care so much about making exactly the same plot, but rather the problem of making an interpretable plot of this type in ggplot2.
